# Declaring a python function with an array parameters and passing an array argument to the function call?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I am a complete newbie to python and attempting to pass an array as an argument to a python function that declares a list/array as the parameter.

I am sure I am declaring it wrong,

here goes:

```
def dosomething(listparam):
         #do something here
dosomething(listargument)
```

Clearly this is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It should work. Could you show some real code?

Comment: Could you provide some more context, maybe the actual code that fails? (If possible, make it a [good example](http://sscce.org/)). And what do you mean by *declaring*?

Comment: oh yes it is absolutely my  bad...i was doing this:
for x in range(len(list)):
      print x;
instead of print list[x] ...thanks all!

Comment: This looks correct; are you getting a specific error message?  Perhaps you have not declared / put something inside listargument?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What you have is on the right track.

```
def dosomething( thelist ):
    for element in thelist:
        print element

dosomething( ['1','2','3'] )
alist = ['red','green','blue']
dosomething( alist )
```

Produces the output:

```
1
2
3
red
green
blue
```

A couple of things to note given your comment above: unlike in C-family languages, you often don't need to bother with tracking the index while iterating over a list, unless the index itself is important. If you really do need the index, though, you can use `enumerate(list)` to get `index,element` pairs, rather than doing the `x in range(len(thelist))` dance.

Comment: I think you mean `enumerate(list)`

Answer (score 23):

Maybe you want to unpack elements of an array, I don't know if I got it, but below an example:

```
def my_func(*args):
    for a in args:
        print(a)

my_func(*[1,2,3,4])
my_list = ['a','b','c']
my_func(*my_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess I'm unclear about what the OP was really asking for... Do you want to pass the whole array/list and operate on it inside the function? Or do you want the same thing done on every value/item in the array/list. If the latter is what you wish I have found a method which works well.

I'm more familiar with programming languages such as Fortran and C, in which you can define elemental functions which operate on each element inside an array. I finally tracked down the python equivalent to this and thought I would repost the solution here. The key is to 'vectorize' the function. Here is an example:

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    if (a>b): return a
    else: return b
vecfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
result=vecfunc([[1,2,3],[5,6,9]],[7,4,5])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[7 4 5]
 [7 6 9]]
```